# How to change the color of columns (DT) according to different ui inputs?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

**The goal:** I want to change the color of specific columns of a `datatable` dependent on the input of 2 different ui inputs. I therefore want to change the color of column A according to input A and the color of column B according to input B (in one table).

**The problem:** If I do it with only one ui input everything works fine but if I add a second, only the second one gets executed. Shiny therefore recognizes the value (changes) of the other one. I tried a lot of things but nothing worked. The example beneath is the code which worked "best".

Here is my example (**Note:** I am working with modules):

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
```

input module

```
 input_ui <- function(id) {
 ns <- NS(id)
 tagList(
  radioButtons(ns("radio1"), label = "Buttons1", choices = c("red", "green")),
  radioButtons(ns("radio2"), label = "Buttons2", choices = c("yellow", "blue"))
 )
}
```

display module

```
 output_show <- function(id) {
 ns <- NS(id)
 tagList(
 DT::dataTableOutput(ns("test_table"))
 )
}
```

server module

```
 output_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
   id,
   function(input, output, session) {
  
   output$test_table <-  DT::renderDataTable({
    mtcars
    df <- mtcars

   if(input$radio1=="red") {
   DT::datatable(df) %>%
     formatStyle("mpg",
                 backgroundColor = "red")
   } else if (input$radio1=="green") {
      DT::datatable(df) %>%
       formatStyle("mpg",
                   backgroundColor = "green")
   }
 
  if(input$radio2=="yellow") {
  DT::datatable(df) %>%
    formatStyle("cyl",
                backgroundColor = "yellow")
  } else if (input$radio2=="blue") {
  DT::datatable(df) %>%
    formatStyle("cyl",
                backgroundColor = "blue")
  }
   
    })
   }
  )
 }
```

UI

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(

   sidebarPanel(
    input_ui("test")),

   mainPanel(
    output_show("test")
   )
  )
 )
```

server

```
 server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output_server("test")
 }

 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason why it is not working on your question post is that you are not modfying your variable `df` when doing if/else statement.
So the `DT::renderDataTable` is rendering only the last one, i.e the one modified by `radio2`. But the modification by `radio1` is erased.

You have several solutions here :

- do all your modifications in one (exemple right below)
- do your modifications one by one but modify your variable everytime. Which means do not write  `DT::datatable(df) %>% formatStyle("mpg",backgroundColor = "green")`, but write something like

```
    df <- DT::datatable(mtcars) 
    if(input$radio1=="red") {
    df <- df %>% formatStyle("mpg",backgroundColor = "red")
    }
```

So my example :
I removed the modules to simplify the code

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("radio1", label = "Buttons1", choices = c("red", "green")),
      radioButtons("radio2", label = "Buttons2", choices = c("yellow", "blue"))
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("test_table")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$test_table <-  DT::renderDataTable({

    req(input$radio1)
    req(input$radio2)

    DT::datatable(mtcars) %>%
      formatStyle("mpg",
                  backgroundColor = input$radio1) %>%
      formatStyle("cyl",
                  backgroundColor = input$radio2)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks! I suspected something like this. You really helped me to unravel my thoughts^^

Comment: Just to make sure I didn't miss anything: is there a specific reason why you are using `req()` or is it just for "safety reasons"?

Comment: Shiny development is my job and i put req() for safety reasons almost everywhere in all my apps. I noticed sometimes with an OS you don't need it, and with the same app deployed on another OS, you get an error and have to put a req ...

Answer (score 0):

Found a soluation myself, although it is not very handy or elegant.

new server module

```
output_server <- function(id) {
 moduleServer(
  id,
  function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$test_table <-  DT::renderDataTable({
    mtcars
    df <- mtcars

    
    if(input$radio1=="red" & input$radio2=="blue") {
      DT::datatable(df) %>%
        formatStyle("mpg", 
                    backgroundColor = "red")%>%
        formatStyle("cyl", 
                    backgroundColor= "blue")
    } else if (input$radio1=="red" & input$radio2=="yellow") {
      DT::datatable(df) %>%
        formatStyle("mpg", 
                    backgroundColor = "red")%>%
        formatStyle("cyl", 
                    backgroundColor= "yellow")
    }  else if (input$radio1=="green" & input$radio2=="blue") {
      DT::datatable(df) %>%
        formatStyle("mpg", 
                    backgroundColor = "green")%>%
        formatStyle("cyl", 
                    backgroundColor= "blue")
    }  else if (input$radio1=="green" & input$radio2=="yellow") {
      DT::datatable(df) %>%
        formatStyle("mpg", 
                    backgroundColor = "green")%>%
        formatStyle("cyl", 
                    backgroundColor= "yellow")
    } 

    })
   }
  )
 }
```